# Replicated circles are blurry in Motion

Tags: video, composing, motion

I'm animating a circle in Motion. I'm using the Sequence Replicator and the Scale setting to make the circles become larger towards the end. 
When I do that however, the circles get blurry, much like if I would use a pixel graphic rather than a circle from Motion. Does anyone know how I can prevent that from happening?
I would have assumed the circles stay crisp and sharp no matter what scale they're applied to. (Preserve scale is ticked on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect occurs if the cell is screened as bitmap. It should be able to avoid it if you activate 3D Rasterization. Click the "3D" checkbox in the Replicator Controls.

Comment: Sure, here's the example. I was trying to make a WIFI-Signal animation.

[Replicator Example](http://files.zettt.de/tmp/Replicator_Example.motn)

Comment: Ah, i see. I slightly missunderstood your description. So i've changed my answer.